# $error for a field on form undefined

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, angularjs

I need to validate an input on a form pre-submitting. I created a directive that validates said input and sets 'valid_amount' to false or true accordingly.

The problem is on the form, I can not seem to evaluate `'formTransfer.amount.$error.valid_amount'`, $error does not exists. Any idea on what might be the problem?

Part of the form

```
<form name='formTransfer' ng-submit='prepare( transfer )' >
 <input amount name='amount' ng-model='transfer.amount' required='required' type='number'>
 <span class='error' ng-show='formTransfer.amount.$error.valid_amount'>This is not valid valid_amount!</span>
```

And the directive:

```
 var AMOUNT_REGEXP = /^(\d*\.\d{1,2}|\d+)$/;

 app.directive("amount", function() {
    return {
      require: "ngModel",
      link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
        return ngModel.$parsers.unshift(function(viewValue) {
          if (AMOUNT_REGEXP.test(viewValue)) {
            ngModel.$setValidity("valid_amount", true);
            viewValue;
          } else {
            ngModel.$setValidity("valid_amount", false);
            undefined;
          }
          return console.log(ngModel);
        });
      }
    };
  });
```

I'm working with HAML and Coffeescript, please let me know if some of the code does not make sense to clarify or post the original code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ngModelController.$parsers](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angModel.NgModelController#%24parsers) array is an array of functions that are being applied to the value entered by user.

[ngModelController.$formatters](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angModel.NgModelController#%24formatters) array is an array of functions being applied to the value that is coming from the model (from the scope).

Your error is not being displayed initially because you're not validating your field for the initial (model) value.

So, you need to adjust your directive as such:

```js
var AMOUNT_REGEXP = /^(\d*\.\d{1,2}|\d+)$/;

app.directive("amount", function() {
  return {
    require: "ngModel",
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {

      function validate(value){
        if (AMOUNT_REGEXP.test(value)) {
          ngModel.$setValidity("valid_amount", true);
          return value;
        } else {
          ngModel.$setValidity("valid_amount", false);  
          return undefined;
        }
      }

      ngModel.$parsers.unshift(validate);
      ngModel.$formatters.unshift(validate);
    }
  };
});
```

[PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/wopn3E9fldT6x4JE4Flz?p=preview)